# Windows 10 Compatibility Mode | Registry Key

Tags: windows

I'm currently packaging an application to run in compatibility mode. I easily found the location where the registry keys are created in the HKLM (for all users) or HKCU (for only the logged on user).

The problem is; which I really don't know if it's a problem, I can set the registry key in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers.  I create a REG_SZ with the name of the key being the path.

E.G.: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplicationDirectory\MyApp.exe

The value of this key is ~WIN7RTM

The problem is this, when I install the application and I create a registry key with this path.  I can click on the shortcut properties and go into the Compatibility Tab and noticed it does not appear it's set to run in Compatibility Mode in Windows 7.

I know I created the correct registry key because I originally created the shortcut through the compatibility tab and clicked "Change Settings for All Users" and then set it to run in Windows 7 there. If I set compatibility mode within the shortcut, I can see it checked. (highlighted in yellow)

[image]

But if I try to set compatibility mode via the registry key and I go into the properties of the EXE or shortcut, the box is not checked.

1. If I set the registry key, how do I verify the application is running in compatibility mode?
2. Is there another way I can set the registry key and be sure it's running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Wow, no one.  LOL.  

If I did not explain something clearly, please let me know.

Comment: This is [**for the user, not the programmer**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100311-00/?p=14643/). Going through all this effort is just a waste of time. You should fix the application so it is compatible. The compatibility mode layers don't do anything magical, they just attempt to restore buggy behavior of older versions. It's much easier to fix the bugs in your program.

Comment: I agree Gary and the vendor has fixed it.  Our company is in the middle of migrating to Windows 10.  The problem is that things are slowly rolling to upgrade the product and the backend database.  They need people to use something now until we deploy the upgraded version.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind folks.  I did a stare and compare on the registry keys that is created.  I did not add a space between the ~ and WIN7RTM.   Once I added a white space, it worked fine.

Before: ~WIN7RTM (not correct)

After: ~ WIN7RTM (correct)

Overlooked it.