# Changing high DPI scaling override property under Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, dpi, highdpi

In the Windows 10 file properties of an executable in the compatibility tab, there is an option to override the default DPI scaling behaviour. The default is "Application", which lets the program handle DPI scaling itself. I'd like to change this option on an executable (not developed by me), which I want to be scaled by Windows (option "System"). How can I change this property programmatically (WinAPI?)?

Comment: This is stored in the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` registry key https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836185/windows-10-compatibility-mode-registry-key by .exe path (value looks like `~ DPIUNAWARE` but it can be a combination). Just set it using the UI and you'll see what it changes. I don't think there's an official API.

Comment: Thanks very much! I don't know if there's little information on the internet on this matter, or I used the wrong keywords to search for it.

Comment: The magic phrase is "Application Compatibility Toolkit".